# Search string in NSMutableArray for showing in Table

Tags: iphone, search, nsmutablearray

Okay, I have an Book Object Class. That has Book.name and Book.id as extensions. 
Book.name being NSString. Which is what should be searchable and listed in UITableView.

NSMutableArray *matchingSymptomsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:50];

```
for(NSMutableArray *letterArray in DataArray){
        for(Book *bk in letterArray){ //Heres the ERROR
            NSLog(@"Uptil NEW");
            if([bk matchesSearchString:searchString]){
                        //I couldnt reach here, according to debugging and Logs//
                [matchingSymptomsArray addObject:bk];
            }
        }
    }
```

DataArray is where all the Books are held.. more than a hundred. Its the main datasource for the UITableView. I'm trying to search and match each letter of the string with the Book.name, but even before I can begin, I cant do the 
for(Book *bk in LetterArray) //producing the error..

What seems to be the problem?

This is the error in console
 **** -[Book countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x55c110
2009-09-29 06:17:41.073 Smart Diagnosis[3897:20b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '** -[Book countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x55c110'

Any work arounds??

thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

for (id bk in letterArray) {   }

Did you check that letterArray isnt nil or empty?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that letterArray isnt nil or empty?

Comment: hmm, thats funny.. Its crashing if I'm calling for letterArray.count!

for(NSMutableArray *letterArray in DataArray){
  NSLog(@"dataarray = %d  letterArray = %d", DataArray.count, letterArray.count); //It stops here.. 
DataArray is filled up fine, with 195 value. But When I add letterarray.count to it, it stops with the same error!.

Im so confused!